# How do I modify mesh attributes to send custom information in Blender?

Tags: scripting, blender, mesh

I have a mesh in 3DS format. I imported this mesh to blender and now, I want to export this mesh back to 3DS but, I want to associate a number (say `id`) with each vertex of this mesh. Now, I only need the x, y and z coordinates of this newly exported 3DS, and I don't really care about the normals or the texture coordinates.

So the way of keeping the IDs intact could be to insert that number in an un-required attribute, let's say the x coordinate of each vertex normal or the first texture coordinate of each vertex.

Here's what I tried with normals:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

object_reference = bpy.context.active_object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(object_reference.data)

for vert in bm.verts:
    vert.normal[0] = vert.index

bm.to_mesh(object_reference.data)
```

But, the normals reverted back to default on export. So, how do I do this?
I couldn't figure out a way to set the texture coordinates, how can I do so? If I can't, then how can I make the vertex normal hack work? Is there a less-hacky way of doing this?

Comment: Normals get re-calculated at various times, making them a bad choice.  If your exporting to 3DS then you would need to consider what data the format exports, maybe you need to export the data you want in your own format and custom import that in 3DS. I haven't used them but bmesh has [custom data layers](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#custom-data-layer-access) - other options may be vertex colour or bevel weight. Also you will find more blender specific help at [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @sambler how about sending the data through the color or the texture coordinates? Also this question was on blender.stackexchange for a while and no one responded. I figured SO has a more active community.

Comment: The uv data doesn't get automatically updated so it should keep the values you put in there - as long as the odd uv data doesn't mess up your materials in 3DS.

Comment: @sambler I don't have problems with messed up materials. How do I modify the uv data though? I failed to find a way.

Comment: [`bpy.context.object.data.uv_layers['UVMap'].data[0].uv.x`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.uv_layers)

Comment: @sambler this doesn't work in edit mode. Also, are the indices in the edit mode different from those in the object mode?

Comment: @sambler Here's the generic problem I'm trying to solve, for which I resorted to this hack: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36675024/2302611